# How to work with 32 and 64 bit DSN Simultaneously?

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, dsn

My application is in classic asp. Till now it is working fine with 32bit windows server and connecting oracle via a system DSN which is prepared with "Microsoft ODBC driver for oracle".
Now, the server has been migrated to 64bit Windows server 2008 R2. We have some third party dlls, which also have 64bit available. So, I deploy the application in IIS 7.5 and it is working fine.

In new server, I am using Oracle driver, as for 64bit, there is no driver of "Microsoft ODBC Driver For Oracle".  Everything is working fine, except, when I try to fetch a record-set, it is returning nothing. No Error message, no data, nothing is coming.

Also, I can't change the app pool compatibility with 32 bit to "True", because, there are some third-party component which will only work in either of one environment. Either 32 bit or 64 bit.

So, my concern is, whether I can work with both the DSN[32 and 64]? OR any other idea to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an OLEDB driver instead.  Oracle certainly provide a 64 bit OLEDB driver, and it could well be installed on your server already.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Here's another useful link, with a very friendly URL

http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

ODBC isn't generally regarded as the best way to go, unless you're using MySQL when it's pretty much your only option